# It is possible to get Assembly Version Attributes of a .net ddl via Java? (Without proxy .net app to retrieve the reflection data)

Tags: java, .net, assemblyversionattribute

I already know other questions which proposes the proxy app solution.

Comment: You can always read the Microsoft docs for the [.Net dll assembly format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/file-format), and parse relevant bytes from the binary file in Java manually.

Comment: Do not repeat the title inside the question, keep the title short and provide the details in the body.

Answer (score 0):

@paulsm4 Thanks for your comment. This works for me.

"You can always read the Microsoft docs for the [.Net dll assembly format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/file-format), and parse relevant bytes from the binary file in Java manually."